# Swagger NPE When Processing Paths

Tags: swagger

I have a very simple OpenAPI/Swagger configuration (openapi.yaml):

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: My Service
  version: 1.0
  description: A description for My Service
basePath: /my-service
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
```

I have the Maven Swagger Codegen Plugin configured. When running,

```
> mvn clean install
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processPaths (DefaultGenerator.java:806)
  at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateApis (DefaultGenerator.java:431)
  at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:746)
  ...
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the `paths` field is required. Even if you do not desire to include any paths, it must be specified with an empty object:

```
paths: {}
```

Updating your openapi.yaml to the following will get rid of the described NPE:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: My Service
  version: 1.0
  description: A description for My Service
basePath: /my-service
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths: {}
```

Comment: And even the brackets `{}`, as I had to notice. @Sam Berry's answer solved the problem for me. Thank you!